# Syncing Kindle for PC with Kindle for Samsung and Kindle for IPad

Tags: kindle, sync

I've searched but been unable to see a solution.

I previously synced my various devices after receiving advice to put my books into collections via Kindle for PC.

I have now again worked on my collections on PC and want to sync all versions of kindle again. But it doesnt want to.

I've done a lot of searching and research but cannot seem to find a solution.

All my books are from amazon.

Comment: Define "doesn't want to." Are you getting an error message? Are you connected with your USB cord and you just don't see the Kindle as a drive?